# c# combobox in datagridview

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, combobox

i'm using datagridviewcomboboxcell to display values. I wish this cells value is int. But: when I open combobox I wish to see a description of each item in combo box. When I pick one the value changes (the combobox is closed) and visible value is only int. Does anyone have idea how to do this?

Like:     selected item: 2

Expanded combobox:      0  - ene
                        1  - due
                        2  - rike
                        3  - fake
Thanks for help.

Comment: You most likely need to set the DataTextField and DataValueField properties.

Comment: I don't get it. WHere in datagridviewcomboboxcell class isn't textfieldcelll

Comment: Is this a WinForm or WebForm (ASP.NET) project?

Comment: Do you see the 'Related' column on the right? Almost all exact title matches for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you would find a way to set the TextField and ValueField I seriously doubt that you would have different text rendered while the control shows the drop down list (number and text) and while it's collapsed and shown only as drop down closed (number only).

what you ask make sense of course but you are not going to get it running with no effort just setting few properties.

To handle this in windows forms you should intercept the event: **EditingControlShowing** and in there, for ComboBox, specify custom values for the control, here is a starting point:

```
 void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
            DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox cmb = e.Control as ComboBox;

                // here you can work on the ComboBox...
            }
        }
```

for more details check here: [DataGridView.EditingControlShowing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx)

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I misread the question. My answer doesn't work if that's what he wants to do...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ValueMember` property to be whatever property in your object is the "id." To set the visible text, assign the property of your object that you want visible to the `DisplayMember` property. If this datagrid is being bound to a database record or some sort, the properties mentioned above should be the names of the table fields you want bound.

Comment: how does additon of valuemember and displaymember coresponds to items.add method?

Comment: Assuming you bound a list of objects, the code baked into the DataGridView will search the objects for property names matching the names you attached to the properties mentioned above.